# RESTAdapter and JSON without root

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

The json I get from the API looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "title1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "title2"
  },
]
```

Unfortunately I can't change the API, so how do I get it to work with the RESTAdapter?

I tried with this code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410016/transform-json-to-an-appropriate-format-for-restadapter-emberjs) :

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    normalizePayload: function(type, payload) {
        return { posts: payload };
    }
});
```

But I get the error *" Error while loading route: Error: No model was found for 'post' "*.

Which I don't understand.

This is my posts Route.

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('posts');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of typeos here.

First since you are dealing with posts, it is probably best to use the `PostSerializer`.

```
App.PostSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalizePayload: function(type, payload) {
    return { posts: payload };
  }
});
```

And when you are requesting models from the server, you want to use the model name, so you would use `post` (not posts).

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('post');
  }
});
```

Comment: You are right, it works now. I was a little confused with the posts/post thing. I got it now. Still trying to wrap my head around it. Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan , Hallelujah!  :-)  Works great for me when requesting records.  How about for adding records?  It's not working for me and I'm wondering if a corresponding change needs to be made for PUT requests.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `normalizePayload` nor `normalize` is working for me. What I am doing is:

```
// app/serializers/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
        var payloadTemp = {}
        payloadTemp[type.typeKey] = payload;
        return this._super(store, type, payloadTemp);
    },
    extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id) {
        var payloadTemp = {}
        payloadTemp[type.typeKey] = [payload];
        return this._super(store, type, payloadTemp, id);
    }
});
```