# JSON Root Name in Serialized Entity

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializerBundle to output JSON data to be consumed by an ember application.  I would like to use the built-in adapters of ember-data and the JSON format that is expected has to have a root name.  My current JSON is as follows:

```
{
     "user_id": 1
     "first": "Dan"
     "email": "dan@email.com" 
 }
```

Ember expects, and what I want is:

```
{
 "user":
   {
     "user_id": 1
     "first": "Dan"
     "email": "dan@email.com" 
    }
}
```

User is the name of the entity.  I'm pretty sure this is just a configuration thing, but looking through the documentation I can't seem to find what to set.  I have tried @XmlRoot, but that doesn't seem to have an affect on the resulting JSON (expected).

Comment: can please you show how it looks in xml  ? @XmlRoot should be correct

Comment: The XML output is correct, but I need the JSON to have a similar Root Name...

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd think it's the API consumers job to bend to the API, not the other way around.

I'd suggest taking a look at this example of massaging the payload into a shape ember likes:

[Transform JSON to an appropriate format for RESTAdapter EmberJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410016/transform-json-to-an-appropriate-format-for-restadapter-emberjs)

Comment: I get that if I was consuming a third party API I would have to create methods to normalize my JSON, but being that I am creating the server API to be consumed by EmberData, I don't see why I shouldn't output the proper JSON from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the controller which extends FOSRestController by sending an array as the view data, I couldn't find a way to do this in the configuration, but I agree a root node setting would be nice.:

```
$fooThing = $em->getRepository('Foo')->find($id);
$view = $this->view(array('foo' => $fooThing), 200);
return $this->handleView($view);
```

I'm pretty sure this is going to mess with my XML, but I'm just starting work on the API so I haven't gotten that far yet.